# Partial differential equation: $u_x(x,y)+u_y(x,y)=2(x+y)u(x,y)$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, linear-pde

I am looking for the most general form of solutions $u:\, \mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{C}$ of the equation $$\frac{\partial u(x,y)}{\partial x}+ \frac{\partial u(x,y)}{\partial y}=2(x+y)u(x,y)$$

If we look for solutions of the form: $u(x,y)=f(x)g(y)$ 
, we find $u(x,y)= \mu e^{x^2+y^2+\lambda (x-y)} , \lambda,\mu \in \mathbb{C}$
If we look for solutions of the form: $$u(x,y)=f(x-y)g(x+y)$$ 
, we find $$u(x,y)=  e^{x^2+y^2} F (x-y)\tag{*}$$ with $F$ an arbitrary function.

Are  all solutions of the form  $(*)$?

Comment: Yes, question edited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's change the variables: $\xi = x + y; \eta = x - y$. We have:

$$u_x = u_{\xi} + u_{\eta} $$
$$u_y = u_{\xi} - u_{\eta} $$

So our equation can be overwritten:

$$u_{\xi} =  \xi u$$

Hence we got:

$$ u = f(\eta) \exp\left(\frac{\xi^2}{2}\right)$$
$$ u = f(x-y) \exp\left(\frac{(x+y)^2}{2}\right) $$

This means that the solution is unique.

Comment: You should not that your form is equivalent to the (*) from the question, since $\frac{(x+y)^2}{2}+\frac{(x-y)^2}{2}=x^2+y^2.$ So for any $f$ we can define $F(z)=e^{-z^2/2}f(z).$ Then $$F(x-y)\exp(x^2+y^2) = f(x-y)\exp((x+y)^2/2)$$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, thank you, I forgot to notice that.

Comment: @Eugene Sirkiza 8  Ok thank's

Comment: Another form $e^{2 x y} f(x-y)$.